# grails 2.1 - Too slow, how to speed up?

Tags: grails

I have just updated from Grails 1.3.7 to Grails 2.1. So far everything works perfectly. The only thing that concerns me a lot is the speed in development.

Until now working in 1.3.7 it was really fast (rendering of a page will take 6 sec.), now the same page takes up to 30 seconds to render.

I have already deactivated all plugins (only hibernate, jquery and tomcat is used) and used the following jvm options:

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=510m
```

as well as Grails options

```
-Ddisable.auto.recompile=true
```

Also some profiling shows that the rendering of the pages itself takes only about 10 seconds, but the strange thing is that after the profiling shows the rendering has been done it still takes about 20 more seconds until the page is loaded in the browser.

Any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 1):

So, problem found.

It turns out that the profiling only was including calls into the view & controller but did not include any of the actions done in the layout.

The missing 20 seconds where in the rendering of the layout.